# Matrix size defined by inputbox, mismatch error

Tags: vba, matrix, mismatch

I wish to define a matrix's size by means of inputbox, but when running the macro it gives of a mismatch error. The macro's goal is to multiply two matrices, it's for an assignment it must be written this way, but it wont get through the first few lines because of this.

This is the Code, notice it errors at the beginning.

```
Sub SumaMatrices()

Dim ai, aj, bi, bj, ci, cj As Integer

j = 1
i = 1

ai = InputBox("Enter number of rows in matrix A.")

aj = InputBox("Enter number of columns in matrix A.")


Dim A(ai, aj) As Single


Do
Do
A(i, j) = InputBox("Enter number in ", i, ", ", j, ".")
j = j + 1
Loop Until j < aj
i = i + 1
Loop Until i < ai

j = 1
i = 1

bi = InputBox("Enter number of rows in matrix A.")
bj = InputBox("Enter number of columns in matrix A.")
Dim B() As Double

Do
Do
B(i, j) = InputBox("Enter number in ", i, ", ", j, ".")
j = j + 1
Loop Until j < bj
i = i + 1
Loop Until i < bi

i = 1
j = 1

If aj = bi Then
ci = ai
cj = bj
Dim C() As Double

k = 1
D = 0
Do
Do
Do
Z = A(i, k) * B(k, j)
D = D + Z
Loop Until k > aj
C(i, j) = D
i = i + 1
Loop Until i > ci
j = j + 1
Loop Until j > cj

If Not aj = bi Then
Messagebox = ("Multiplication is not possible.")
End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: there are some problems within your code. You didn't write in which line you get an error. If it is in `InputBox` line then make it in this way: `A(i, j) = InputBox("Enter number in " & i & ", " & j & ".")`

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that you are even getting that `Mismatch Error` first. You should be getting `Constant Expression Required - Compile Error` first.

Couple of things

1. Use `Option Explicit` It will force you to declare variables explicitly
2. Unlike `VB.Net`, you have to declare each and every variable specificly. Consider this line `Dim ai, aj, bi, bj, ci, cj As Integer`. Here only `cj` will be declared as `Integer` and the rest will be declared as `Variant`
3. `Dim A(ai, aj) As Single` You cannot declare an array like that. This is the line which will error out first. with `Constant Expression Required - Compile Error`. Read the web on `REDIM Arrays`
4. Now to your main error. `Mismatch Error`. You are getting that error because you are trying to store a `String` in a `Single` Array in the line `A(i, j) = InputBox("Enter number in ", i, ", ", j, ".")` You can either use `CSng` to convert that string to `Single` or you can use `Application.Inputbox` with `Type:=1`  Read Excel's help on `Application.Inputbox`
5. Use Proper `Error Handling`. Your code will error out if the user presses `Cancel` in the Inputbox. Proper `Error Handling` will also cover other errors that your code might encounter.